# Adding button and functions in daycell using vue3 and fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, vuejs3, quasar

I'm creating a log view screen using fullcalendar and vue3. I want to render buttons in each day cell where we can download the log record of that day.

this is sample design;

[image: design]

I asked a similar question before and
I created a codepen example like this; https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/rNrdeJp
but this example doesn't work with vue3. I've been working with this screen for quite a long time and now I can't see what's missing, please enlighten me.

here is my fullcalendar options;

```
calendarOptions: {
        plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
        initialView: "dayGridMonth",
        // dateClick: this.handleDateClick,
        headerToolbar: {
          start: "",
          center: "title",
          end: "today,prevYear,prev,next,nextYear",
        },
        locale: "tr",
        events: [
          { title: "event 1", date: "2023-01-01" },
          { title: "event 2", date: "2023-01-02" },
        ],
        dayCellContent: (date) => {
            html: `
       <div class="day-number-text">${date.dayNumberText}</div>
      <div class="btn-group calendar-buttons" style="margin-top:10px;">
        <q-btn  class="btn btn-info download-btn" @click="eventClick"></q-btn>
        <q-btn  class="btn btn-info save-btn" v-on:click="handleButtonClick(date,2)"></q-btn>
        <q-btn  class="btn btn-info share-btn" v-on:click="handleButtonClick(date,3)"></q-btn>
      </div>
      `,
        },
      },
```

> The real question is; As I mentioned above, when adding the buttons
> to the calendar where I can view or download the daily log records, is
> it reasonable to add an onclick event to the buttons using
> daycellcontent or use the events and eventClick event already in
> fullcalendar?

note: I'm using quasar framework with vue and I'm still a rookie in all these technologies I use.

Comment: `doesn't work with vue3`...because? Does a specific problem occur? e.g. an error, or some specific unexpected behaviour?

Comment: I didn't encounter any specific error but the latest version of fullcalendar strangely daycellcontent is not working so I downgraded it to v5 and it worked successfully. @ADyson

Comment: Ok. You should probably raise a bug about that - see https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs

Answer (score 0):

the latest version of fullcalendar strangely daycellcontent is not working so I downgraded it to v5 and it worked successfully.